# What is reference path in vscode

Tags: jquery, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded Visual Studio Code for linux, and I am playing around with it. I wanted to use jQuery intellisense with it, and found a way to do it on the internet. Once I did it some sort of directive was added to my js file.

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

what does /// mean to pure javascript? it's not a comment, so how does javascript interpreter deal with this. also I am unable to find the path `typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts` in the local vscode folder. (although there is a typings folder there is no folder or file named jquery). So from where is this file linked to my js file?

Comment: After `//` rest of a line considered a comment. So, it is a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Vscode** will see :

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

and know it must use `intellisense jQuery`.

Intellisense is a vscode feature that provides instant context-aware help when writing code. It has nothing to do with your own sourcecode.

Here a really good explanation : [vscode intellisense](http://www.johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: what does the /// mean to javascript?

Comment: Microsoft imposed it. It may be a way for them to be sure this line concerns vscode and is not a user line. It is no problem, in your js code it is not read. It could have been `///////////// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>`, they just decided `///`.