# How to access functions defined from one file to other via intellisense with vscode (visual studio) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

Consider folder structure as below in javascript project built-in Visual Studio 1.43

```
/Folder1
   /testFunctions1.js
       /function1()
       /function2()
       ...

/Folder2
   /testFunctions2.js
      require('testFunctions1.js') //to include 

      functio //Here If I press ctrl+space, I expect suggestions of functions defined in testFunctions1.js
```

How do I achieve it in java-script?

pre-reqs: javascript/Visual Studi 1.43 (2020)

**Update 1:**

```
../Folder1/testFunctions1.js
test1 : function()
{
    ..
    ..
}

test2 : function()
{
    ..
    ..
}

../Folder2/testFunctions2.js
require('../Folder1/testFunctions1.js')

test (ctrl+space) //expect suggestions here
```

**Update 2:**

```
   function doSomething1() {
    ..
    }

    function doSomething2() {
    ..
    }
```

If I include above with reference, I get suggestions - It works.

But If I have functions in below format then, it fails. I want doSomething in suggestions.

```
//testFunctions1.js
define('../mypageobjects/PageObject.js', 
[
   '../test/tests.js'
], 

function (PageObject,commonLibWidget){
    var test = PageObject.extend('test', {       
    check: function () {
        return true;
    },

    selectors: {
        //home page
        widgetHeader: '.moduleHeader_tle',
    },

    commands: {

        doSomething1: function(){ //I want this function name - doSomething1
            return this
        },

         doSomething2: function(){ //I want this function name - doSomething2
            return this
        },     

    }  //commands close

    }); //pageobject.extend
    return test;
}); //main function
```

Comment: you have to import the functions first

Comment: @rioV8 Yes. I have included testFunction1.js via require but still I fail to get suggestions of functions via intellisense. You have any sample or examples?

Comment: show the code you have in `testFunctions1.js` and `testFunctions2.js`

Comment: this is not enough, just show the actual `.js` files, both

Comment: @rioV8 updated under 'Update' section.

Comment: what kind of Javascript is `testFunctions1.js`? How do you use `test1` in `testFunctions1.js`? And read the docs about `require`.

Comment: @rioV8 we write modular(amd) and promise based JavaScript functions on node js.

Comment: In which dialect is this valid Javascript? Construct a `testFunctions1.js` with functions that print something on the console. And show the file that actually works.

Comment: `test1 : function() {}` isn't a valid way to define a function. In this case `test1` is treated as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and not a function declaration. Another way to define it is `const test1 = function() {}`, which should still work with intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following comment to the top of your `testFunctions2.js` file:

```js
/// <reference path="../Folder1/testFunctions1.js" />
```

[image: example - vscode in action]

This should work in Visual Studio and VSCode.

See also: [What is reference path in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136319/what-is-reference-path-in-vscode)

Comment: I tried but no suggestions appear. ANy VS Code version dependency?

Comment: I'm using VSCode 1.44.2, but it's been working for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Thank you for the gif, really appreciate. I tried with simple js function syntax, it worked as you had mentioned but we have a different way of creating function for our internal usage related to automation. I have updated my query above where I still see issue with suggestions. Is it because of the format?

Comment: I left a comment on the question, but yes, the problem is the way that the function is defined.

Comment: yes, I saw it and tried but didn't work. I think it's limitation to our script format. Any other workaround you suggest in this case like exporting function name and getting them as suggestion etc., Our only try, as it will help users to understand already available function and use them before scripting same.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but I got to the same problem.

I think that there is a feature now related to the file [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson).

Putting this file in the root folder, I could get the intellisense for functions and objects methods, look these examples below.

(note: in the case of object methods, the object needs to be define with the `let` statement)

[image]